# Yet another Ant + JUnit classpath problem

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit, classpath

I'm developing an Eclipse SWT application using Eclipse. There are also some JUnit 4 tests, which test some DAO's. But when I try to run the tests via an ant build, all of the tests fail, because the test classes aren't found.

Google brought up about a million of people who all have the same problem, but none of their solutions seem to work for me -.- .

These are the contents of my build.xml file:

```
<property name="test.reports" value="./test/reports" />
<property name="classes" value="build" />


<path id="project.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${classes}" />
</path>

<target name="testreport">
    <mkdir dir="${test.reports}" />
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="no" haltonfailure="no">
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.reports}" >
            <fileset dir="${classes}">
                <include name="**/Test*.class" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <formatter type="xml" />

        <classpath refid="project.classpath" />


    </junit>

    <junitreport todir="${test.reports}">
        <fileset dir="${test.reports}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report todir="${test.reports}" />
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

The test classes are in the build-directory together with the application classes, although they are in some subfolders according to their packages.

Maybe this is important too: At first Ant complained that JUnit wasn't in its classpath, but since I put it there (with the eclipse configuration editor) it complains about JUnit being in its classpath twice.

```
WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 
   [junit]          jar:file:C:/Users/as df/Documents/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20090120-1145/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
   [junit]      and jar:file:/C:/Users/as%20df/Documents/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20090120-1145/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
```

I've tried specifying each and every subdirectory, each and every class file, I've tried filesets and filelists, nothing seems to work.

Thanks for your help, I've been sitting for hours on this thing now...

Comment: Would you mind to write the username "as_df" instead of "as df" (replacing blank by underscore)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem 'multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit'. The problem went away when I renamed by Eclipse_Home directory and removed special characters from it. The path had '[1]' in it which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this only when using the 'fork=true' option to the junit task. It was happening because my ANT_HOME had '..' in it (e.g. '/3rdparth/jboss/jboss-5/../tools'). Once I reduced that path, the 'multiple versions of ant' warning went away.

Answer (score 1):

This Ant build.xml works fine for me.  Check out the properties to see if the directory structure matches yours; adjust as needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="xslt-converter" basedir="." default="package">

    <property name="version" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="haltonfailure" value="no"/>

    <property name="out" value="out"/>

    <property name="production.src" value="src"/>
    <property name="production.lib" value="lib"/>
    <property name="production.resources" value="config"/>
    <property name="production.classes" value="${out}/production/${ant.project.name}"/>

    <property name="test.src" value="test"/>
    <property name="test.lib" value="lib"/>
    <property name="test.resources" value="config"/>
    <property name="test.classes" value="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}"/>

    <property name="exploded" value="out/exploded/${ant.project.name}"/>
    <property name="exploded.classes" value="${exploded}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="exploded.lib" value="${exploded}/WEB-INF/lib"/>

    <property name="reports.out" value="${out}/reports"/>
    <property name="junit.out" value="${reports.out}/junit"/>
    <property name="testng.out" value="${reports.out}/testng"/>

    <path id="production.class.path">
        <pathelement location="${production.classes}"/>
        <pathelement location="${production.resources}"/>
        <fileset dir="${production.lib}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            <exclude name="**/junit*.jar"/>
            <exclude name="**/*test*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="test.class.path">                            
        <path refid="production.class.path"/>
        <pathelement location="${test.classes}"/>
        <pathelement location="${test.resources}"/>
        <fileset dir="${test.lib}">
            <include name="**/junit*.jar"/>
            <include name="**/*test*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="testng.class.path">
        <fileset dir="${test.lib}">
            <include name="**/testng*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <available file="${out}" property="outputExists"/>

    <target name="clean" description="remove all generated artifacts" if="outputExists">
        <delete dir="${out}" includeEmptyDirs="true"/>
        <delete dir="${reports.out}" includeEmptyDirs="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="create" description="create the output directories" unless="outputExists">
        <mkdir dir="${production.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${test.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${reports.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${junit.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${testng.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${exploded.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${exploded.lib}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="compile all .java source files" depends="create">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="production.class.path" refid="production.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${production.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="${out}/production/${ant.project.name}" debug="on" source="${version}">
            <classpath refid="production.class.path"/>
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*Test.java"/>
        </javac>
        <javac srcdir="${test.src}" destdir="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}" debug="on" source="${version}">
            <classpath refid="test.class.path"/>
            <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="junit-test" description="run all junit tests" depends="compile">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="test.class.path" refid="test.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${test.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="${haltonfailure}">
            <classpath refid="test.class.path"/>
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${junit.out}">
                <fileset dir="${test.src}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
        <junitreport todir="${junit.out}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.out}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report todir="${junit.out}" format="frames"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>

    <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpathref="testng.class.path"/>
    <target name="testng-test" description="run all testng tests" depends="compile">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="test.class.path" refid="test.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${test.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <testng classpathref="test.class.path" outputDir="${testng.out}" haltOnFailure="${haltonfailure}" verbose="2" parallel="methods" threadcount="50">
            <classfileset dir="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}" includes="**/*.class"/>
        </testng>
    </target>

    <target name="exploded" description="create exploded deployment" depends="testng-test">
        <copy todir="${exploded.classes}">
            <fileset dir="${production.classes}"/>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${exploded.lib}">
            <fileset dir="${production.lib}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="package" description="create package file" depends="exploded">
        <jar destfile="${out}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${production.classes}" includes="**/*.class"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Hm seems like that solved pat of the problem, but now I get

"Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the VM exit"