# GWT Junit ant warning: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit

Tags: java, gwt, ant, junit

Noob question: still learning GWT, and I just set up my project to use GWTTestCase by running `webAppCreator -junit`. It set up everything nicely and I'm able to write and run test cases, but invoking `ant test.dev` gives me this warning:

```
[junit] WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 
[junit]     jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
[junit] and jar:file:/home/webbtra/proj/myProject/trunk/lib/gwt-dev.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
```

It doesn't seem to be breaking anything so I don't want to spend a ton of time on it. Just figured I'd post here to see if anyone has some insight on this. Thanks.

-tjw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is a [bug](http://teamsys.intellij.net/issue/TW-12516?query=#unresolved).

Comment: Your link requires login... can you copy/paste?

Comment: @Travis I can't find right now, but you may be interested in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805574/yet-another-ant-junit-classpath-problem